# How to display the data by using checkbox's and after uncheck it must display the previous state?

Tags: reactjs

I am developing one e-comm site using reactJS which is having checkbox's in sidebar and i written logic but it is selecting all checkbox's and filtering the products and displayed the filtered data but when i uncheck, it is not displaying previous state. please help how to resolve this issue.

```
   class DashView extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
   super(props);
   this.state = {
    products: [],
      isChecked: false
     };
   this.getProductList = this.getProductList.bind(this);
   // this.clearCheck = this.clearCheck.bind(this);
  }
 componentDidMount() {
  // const { isChecked } = this.state;
  let apiUrl = ` https://api.myjson.com/bins/4xc0c`;
 axios.get(apiUrl).then(res => {
  // console.log(res.data.products);
  this.setState({
    products: res.data.products,
    isChecked : this.state.isChecked
    });
   });
   }

  getProductList = item => {
  const { products, isChecked } = this.state;
  const prevProducts = this.state.products;
  console.log(products);
   // console.log(item);
  let newProduct = [];
  if ((isChecked === false && item === "smartphone") || item === "iphone") {
  for (let i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
    if (products[i].ptype === item) {
      console.log(item);
      newProduct.push(products[i]);
    }
   }
  console.log(newProduct);
  this.setState({
    products: newProduct,
    isChecked: !isChecked
    });
   } else {
  console.log("unchecked");
  console.log(prevProducts);

  this.setState({
    prevProducts : this.state.products,
    isChecked : !isChecked
  })
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

> const prevProducts = this.state.products; // NOT TRUE

`this.state.products` contains **actually rendered data**, it's overwritten with filtered onces

> ```
>  console.log(newProduct);  // filtered
>   this.setState({
>     products: newProduct,  // for rendering
>     isChecked: !isChecked
>   });
> } else {
>   console.log("unchecked");
>   this.setState({
>     prevProducts : this.state.products, // doesn't make sense here
>     isChecked : !isChecked
>   })
> }
> ```

it should be:

```
    console.log(newProduct); // filtered
    this.setState({
      prevProducts : this.state.products,  // backup
      products: newProduct,  // for rendering
      isChecked: !isChecked
    });
  } else {
    console.log("unchecked");
    console.log(prevProducts);

    this.setState({
      products : this.state.prevProducts, // restore, not filtered
      isChecked : !isChecked
    })
  }
```

You can also backup data just at loading time:

```
this.setState({
  products: res.data.products,  // for rendering
  prevProducts: res.data.products, // for restoring from filtering
  isChecked : this.state.isChecked
});
```